# React.js on Rails error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kTSsZrub5iE) tutorial on how to integrate react.js into rails and when I pre compile my assets I get an error with this code stating that `(data) => this.setState({statuses: data});` causes `SyntaxError: unknown: Unexpected token (14:44)` I tried many things to get it to work and when I delete the semi-colon at the end it works except that the interval no longer gets called the console will say alert twice when the page is refreshed and then never again.

```
var StatusesContainer = React.createClass ({
    componentWillMount() {
        this.fetchStatuses();
        setInterval(this.fetchStatuses(), 1000);
    },

    fetchStatuses() {
        console.log("alert");
        $.getJSON(
            this.props.statusesPath,
            {
                space_id: this.props.space_id
            },
            (data) => this.setState({statuses: data});
        );
    },

    getInitialState() {
        return ({ statuses: [] });
    },

    render() {
        return  (<RecentStatuses statuses={ this.state.statuses }/>);
    }
});
```

Comment: I created a similar approach but with comments. look into my project and see if it can help you. used Rails 5, react-rails gem. 


  [1]: https://github.com/mrvncaragay/rails-reactOnComments/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/components/CommentBox/CommentBoxX.js.jsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.getJSON(
    this.props.statusesPath,
    {
        space_id: this.props.space_id
    },
    (data) => this.setState({statuses: data});
);
```

Here is the problem: `(data) => this.setState({statuses: data});`, you should use `,` not `;`

Comment: That works but the interval doesnt trigger ever second any idea why?

Comment: @Bevilacqua you should write it like this `setInterval(this.fetchStatuses, 1000);` don't use `this.fetchStatuses`, actually, what you run is the result of this.fetchStatuses function return.